# How can I use TouchEvent Typescript type in an Angular2 directive HostListener in Safari on MacOSX

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

Using the

```
TouchEvent
```

type in a directive is resulting in the following error in Safari desktop

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TouchEvent
```

The Typescript source code is

```
@HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
onTouchstart(event: TouchEvent) {
  // ... does something with event.
}
```

The generated erring code is

```
    __decorate([
        core_1.HostListener('touchstart', ['$event']), 
        __metadata('design:type', Function), 
        __metadata('design:paramtypes', [TouchEvent]), 
        __metadata('design:returntype', void 0)
    ], MyTouchDirective.prototype, "onTouchstart", null);
```

Changing the type to

```
any
```

fixes, but should it be possible to use this type? I thought in general the types never made it to the resulting javascript. I do have other references to TouchEvent in Typescript classes in the same program that do not cause the issue.

Comment: There seems to be a reference to the same message here: https://github.com/angular-slider/ng5-slider/issues/4 I wonder if you can post the package.json you have to see if this is specific to a given verson.